# laravel view doesn't show data after adding new route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

It works really good, but when I've created new page something goes wrong and now my blog view doesn't show data, but blogs view still correctly show data . I am trying to show detailed data of each blog when user click on button "Details"

MainController:

```
  public function blog(Blogs $blog)
   {

       return view('blog', compact('blog'));
   }
   public function blogs()
   {
       return view('blogs',['blogs' => Blogs::all(),]);
   }
```

blogs.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', __('main.blogs'))

@section('content')
   <div class="row">
       @foreach($blogs as $blog)
           @include('layouts.cardBlog', compact('blog'))
       @endforeach
   </div>
@endsection
```

and cardBlog.blade.php:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
       <img src="{{($blog->image) }}">
       <div class="caption">
           <h3>{{ $blog->title }}</h3>
           <p>{{  $blog->body }}</p>
           <p>
               <a href="{{route('blog', $blog->id) }}"
                  class="btn btn-default"
                  role="button">@lang('main.more')</a>
               @csrf
           </p>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

blog.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', __('main.blogs'))

@section('content')
   <h1>{{ $blog->title}}</h1>

   <img src="{{$blog->image }}">
   <p>{{ $blog->body }}</p>
@endsection
```

web.php:

```
 Route::get('/', 'MainController@index')->name('index');

   Route::get('/categories', 'MainController@categories')->name('categories');
   Route::get('/about', 'MainController@aboutus')->name('about');
   Route::get('/contact-us', 'ContactUSController@contactUS')->name('contact-us');
   Route::post('contactus', ['as'=>'contactus.store','uses'=>'ContactUSController@contactSaveData']);
   Route::get('/contacts', 'MainController@contacts')->name('contacts');


   Route::get('/blogs', 'MainController@blogs')->name('blogs');
   Route::get('/blog/{id}', 'MainController@blog')->name('blog');


   Route::get('/intership', 'MainController@intership')->name('intership');
   Route::get('/{category}', 'MainController@category')->name('category');
   Route::get('/{category}/{product}/{skus}', 'MainController@sku')->name('sku');
   Route::post('subscription/{skus}', 'MainController@subscribe')->name('subscription');
```

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What's is the error that it shown?

I suggest use "compact" in this line code

```
return view('blogs',['blogs' => Blogs::all(),]);
```

Something like this

```
public function blogs()
{
    $blogs = Blogs::all();
    return view('blogs',compact('blogs'));
}
```

Comment: It's show no errors, it's just show no data, just blank, but previosly it worked really good but after adding category here is a problem

Comment: The data is coming into view?

Try put a log in the view just to know if the data is being received, something like that:
    {{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($blog) }}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function blog($id)
{
   $blog = Blogs::findOrFail($id)
    return view('blog', compact('blog'));
}
```

Comment: Have a Nice Day, Happy Coding